# How to get the message id of previous message in Telegram using node-telegram-bot-api?

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I'm developing a Telegram bot using Node.js and node-telegram-bot-api library. I want to get the id of the previous message in the chat. How can I achieve this?

I tried using this [https://api.telegram.org/botХХХХ:ХХХХХХ/getUpdates?offset=-1](https://api.telegram.org/bot%D0%A5%D0%A5%D0%A5%D0%A5:%D0%A5%D0%A5%D0%A5%D0%A5%D0%A5%D0%A5/getUpdates?offset=-1)
but it gives the following error message:

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict: can't use getUpdates method while webhook is active; use deleteWebhook to delete the webhook first"}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [Telegram docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api):

> There are two mutually exclusive ways of receiving updates for your bot - the `getUpdates` method on one hand and webhooks on the other.

Later, in the description of [getUpdates](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates) method:

> This method will not work if an outgoing webhook is set up.

Basically, there are two methods of how to receive updates (messages, new users etc.) of your Telegram bot. One is via `getUpdates` method - when using this method, you should run `getUpdates` method regularly to receive all the new updates.

The second method is via webhook - you set up a url where Telegram will send a request whenever your bot receives an Update. In most cases this is a more practical way to receive Updates, albeit a bit harder to implement.

These two methods are mutually exclusive - if you have webhook set up, you can't use `getUpdates` method. The solution, if you want to use `getUpdates` method, is to delete the webhook with the [deleteWebhook](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletewebhook) method.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I'm using Webhooks as I have deployed my bot on a server, is there a way to get the id of the previous message?

Comment: Unfortunately no, if you didn't save the `Update` with the message somewhere. Good idea is to always save the `Update` objects in a database if you want to work with them later.